# Eclipse can not save file or call hierarchy file PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

When i typing something and save a php file. it is normal. 
**but i write a function and save or call hierarchy action.**  ==> There are a error. I saw that parameter of function is reason. 

 How to fix it on eclipse. 

 PHP version: 5.5.15

 Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

 PHP addon eclipse: 4.1 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try nightly build of PDT (http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/) or report issue to PDT (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT)